# Sed multiline regular expression issue

Tags: bash, shell, sed

#### File content:

```
abc def
ijk lmn
opq rst
uvw xyz
```

```
sed '/\(.*\)def/{N;s/\(.*\)def\n\(.*\)lmn/Replaced\nSuccess/}' file
```

#### Output:

```
Replaced
Success
opq rst
uvw xyz
```

Works as expected.

#### However for file content:

```
2013-09-17-01:02:43 User: ID_123456@some.tld
2013-09-17-01:02:43 Last login time: Never
hello
how are you
catch up tmrw
```

```
sed '/\(.*\)tld/{N;s/\(.*\)tld\n\(.*\)Never/Replaced\nSuccess/}' file
```

This doesn't work.

#### Expected Output:

```
Replaced
Success
hello
how are you
catch up tmrw
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: Is it always the first two lines that you need to replace ?

Comment: Works for me, I get the expected output.

Comment: @iamauser No not necessarily

Comment: @choroba, i'm trying to run it even now, still the issue

Comment: Man i'm doing the copy/paste too, still not working

Comment: @user1502952 I concur with choroba.  I have simplified the regex a bit in my answer.

Comment: Do you have whitespace at the end of the line? What version of sed?

Comment: Also, there's no reason for any of those parentheses. And in the first `/\(.*\)tld/`, there's no reason for the `.*` either - `/tld/` will do the same thing, much more efficiently.

Comment: @Kevin yes i will keep that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written does work. To make it more readable, this works too.

```
sed '/.*tld/{N;s/.*tld\n.*Never/Replaced\nSuccess/}' file
```

Comment: Hey thanks, mine and yours both working.. may be there was some case with the text file content.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file ends with LF and and not CRLF. Try to run it with dos2unix before running it with sed.

```
dos2unix file
```

Or completely strip off its trailing spaces (includes `\r`)

```
sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*$//' file
```